# NestJS sharing libraries

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, nestjs

How does one share libraries in [NestJS](https://nestjs.com/)? I am creating a [NestJS](https://nestjs.com/) microservices application and my current structure is:

[image]

This is my first time using [NestJS](https://nestjs.com/) and I could really use the help I need in also structuring my if there is a better way. Currently, my libraries are scoped to the main app but I want them to be shared, thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "share libraries"? Meaning you want to have Nest specific functionality that can be used in multiple Nest projects?

Comment: @nerdybeast yes exactly, such that when i create a library for a specific functionality, i will be able to use that library in my different projects. am willing to restructure my application if y structuring is not efficient enough, mind you am totally new in Nest

Comment: In that case I would definitely avoid having "access-request" as a nested folder in your project. When projects have nested `package.json` files and `node_modules`, all kinds of screwy things happen down the road. You need to make `access-request` it's own dedicated npm package that you would install into your current project (or any other project for that matter).

I would recommend using npm scoped packages for this.

Answer (score 2):

You can install package from folder.

`npm i services/access-request`

Answer (score 1):

You can consider using Monorepo structure, quoting from [the documentation](https://docs.nestjs.com/cli/monorepo):

> monorepo mode: this mode treats code artifacts as part of a lightweight monorepo, and may be more appropriate for teams of developers and/or multi-project environments. It automates parts of the build process to make it easy to create and compose modular components, promotes code re-use, makes integration testing easier, makes it easy to share project-wide artifacts

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [Symbolic Link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link) to the main app folder in the second app folder and keeping only the folder in the main app and it should work like a charm.

You can also use environment variables to set it on the folder location but I wont advise you that one because on a restart you will lose the Variable just run this in a terminal:

```
$ export NODE_PATH='yourdir'/node_modules
```

There is another alternative using yarn as package manager because it supports changing the library location you can create a **.yarnrc** file and place the following:

```
# ./.yarnrc
--modules-folder web/vendor
```